# How can I speed up this query/page?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

In my Rails app, I have a `TimeEntry` model that references several other objects. Here is the migration:

```
class CreateTimeEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :time_entries do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :customer, foreign_key: true
      t.references :site, foreign_key: true
      t.date :work_date
      t.integer :hours
      t.integer :minutes
      t.references :service, foreign_key: true
      t.references :task, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've put together a report that requires fields from the `User`, `Site` and `Task` association, using this code:

```
@time_entries = TimeEntry.joins(:customer, :site)
.where('time_entries.work_date >= ? AND time_entries.work_date <= ?', @start_date, @end_date)
.where(customer: @customer)
```

*NOTE: `@customer` is loaded in a `before_action` and can be either a single customer or all 300+ customers*

For presentation in my view, I then group the customers together in the controller by name:

```
@time_entry_customers = @time_entries.group_by { |time| time.customer.name }
```

The performance is as follows:
`Completed 200 OK in 12308ms (Views: 8508.7ms | ActiveRecord: 924.5ms)`

So, the query's not blazing fast, but the VIEW is the real problem. I do more grouping in the view, by a customer's sites:

```
<% @time_entry_customers.each do |customer, time| %>
  <tr class="success">
    <td colspan="6">
      <strong><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <%= customer %></strong>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <% time.group_by { |t| t.site.url }.each do |site, time_entries| %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="site-row" colspan="5"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <%= site %></td>
    </tr>

      <% time_entries.each do |time_entry| %>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td><%= time_entry.work_date %></td>
        <td><%= time_entry.try(:user).try(:full_name) %></td>
        <td><%= time_entry.task.name %></td>
        <td><%= time_entry.hours %> : <%= time_entry.minutes %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="info" colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Total Time for <%= site %></td>
    <td class="info"><%= sum_time_entries_as_hours_and_minutes(time_entries) %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Between the controller and the view, this ends up being thousands of queries (there are ~47000 `TimeEntries` and ~400 `Customers`)

How can I refactor this for performance?

None of the database tables have any indices, except on `users.email`.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of approaches to solve this problem depending on the use case for this page and the performance expectations.

**Option 1**: Since you mention there are 47k rows that are displayed in the page, user might not need to see all the data at once. So you can show the high level summary first (total time spent on site for each customer and time) and then provide option for each site and customer row to expand further to show the individual time entries. To do this in most effective way, you can do the grouping at DB level by using `group` method in `ActiveRecord` and `pluck` the customer_id, customer_name, site_id, site_name, total time spent.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

**Option 2**: Considering that displaying all the 47k records at once is must, it is preferable to query the only displayed columns instead of loading the whole object hierarchy. This is going to perform much better compared to loading all the objects.The following code is not tested, but it gives you an idea.

```
TimeEntry.joins(:customer, :site, :user, :task)..where('time_entries.work_date >= ? AND time_entries.work_date <= ?', @start_date, @end_date).pluck('time_entries.work_date,users.full_name,time_entries.hours,time_entries.minutes,tasks.name, customers.id, customers.name,sites.id, sites.url').order('customers.id,sites.id')
```

The above query will return array of all the 47k rows. You can either do group_by on customers.id and sites.id or since they are already sorted by customer and site, you can just loop through all the rows and whenever you encounter change in customer or site compared to previous row, you can display those headers.